# HTML Form Control Line Break

Tags: html, forms, drop-down-menu

Is there a way to force a line break in a form control in HTML. I'm using drop-down menus, and some of the choices are taking up a little too much space. I'd like to break them into multiple lines if possible. Any ideas?

Edit:
Heres the code for the problematic menu:

```
<select name="Select1" multiple="multiple">
                    <option selected="selected">(Any)</option>
                    <option>Acadia National Park</option>
                    <option>Alaska Railroad</option>
                    <option>Arapho-Roosevelt<br/>National Forest</option>
                    <option>BLM</option>
                    <option>Cades Cove Heritage Tours</option>
                    <option>Cape Cod Commission</option>
                    <option>Cape Cod National Seashore</option>
                    <option>Cape Cod Regional Transit Authority</option>
                    <option>City of Baltimore DOT</option>
                    <option>City of Commerce City</option>
                    <option>City of Flagstaff</option>
                    <option>City of Jacksonville</option>
                    <option>City of Lowell, MA</option>
                    <option>City of New Bedford, Office of Planning</option>
                    <option>City of Augustine, FL</option>
                    <option>City of The Dalles</option>
                    <option>City of Visalia</option>
                    <option>Codevisa Transit with Municipality of San Juan
                    </option>
                    <option>Colonial National Historical Park</option>
                    <option>Cuyahoga Valley National Park</option>
                    <option>Cuyahoga Valley Scenic Railroad</option>
                    <option>Delaware Water Gap National Recreation Area
                    </option>
                    <option>Denali National Park and Preserve</option>
                    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the width of the drop-down menu. Can you post the code you currently have?

Comment: Changing the width just cuts off the choices that exceed that width, but I'd like them to be able to see the full entry. This doesn't force a line break, like I'd like to see, but just shortens the viewing width.

Comment: Ah, from what I know you can't add a line break within option element.

Comment: If you look at this example, you can incorporate javascript to get the desired look. http://forum.weborum.com/lofiversion/index.php/t2756.html

Comment: I'm trying to keep form as simple as possible for availability purposes. Do you know of any way using HTML. Not everyone uses javascript.

Comment: If you want a dirty method, you can line break the options by <options value="1">dataone</options><options value="2">datatwo</options><options value="3">data</options><options value="3">three</options>. That will get the look you want but if you select the last two option, it will show as independent options but contain the same value. Could be confusing to some. I'm afraid HTML is limited in this case.